# how to see the connected device to my hotspot in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: network-manager, sharing

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I have make a wifi hotspot using kde-nm-connection-editor.

Now I am looking for a way to I can see the device that connected to it.

I try nmap but that what I have got the following terminal output for `sudo nmap -sP 154.96.48.199`:

[image: terminal output for sudo nmap -sP 154.96.48.199]

Answer (score 2):

`arp -a` should return you a list of all connected devices. You should run this command within the server that runs hotspot.

Comment: how to run it within the server that runs hotspot ??

Comment: via ssh connection